# Python, Scrapy, multiple items and links

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I'm working on learning web scraping and doing some personal projects to get going. I've been able to learn some of the basics but having trouble with saving the scraped data to a csv file.

```
import scrapy


class ImdbHmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "imdb_hm"
    allowed_domains = ["www.imdb.com/"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.imdb.com/list/ls069761801/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//div[@class="lister-list"]')

        for titles in title:
            title_name = titles.xpath("./div/div/h3/a/text()").get()


        yield {'title_name':title_name,}
```

When I run this, I only get the first item, "Harvest Moon". If I change the title_name line ending to .getall(), I do get them all in the terminal window but in the CSV file, it all runs together.

[excel file showing the titles in one cell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUIQk.png)

in the terminal window, I'm running:   scrapy crawl imdb_hm -O imdb.csv

any help would be very much appreciated.

I have gotten samples of code that will scrape multiple items and put them in a csv file on each line. then i replaced the sample code with the site i'm trying to scrape and do not get the same result.

I'm expecting the have a csv file of all the movie titles in each line.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Read the scrapy documentation, start with small simple projects. Your current question is actually multiple questions that already have answers, please search them first.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to iterate a sequence of length 1. This can be determined both by the behavior you have described and by simply looking at the html for the page and seeing that there is only one `div` element with a class of `lister-list`.

In order to iterate over all of the titles then you need to use a selector that captures all of the elements separately by pointing it too an element that occurs once for every item you are seeking to extract.  In your case you can select the children of the `lister-list`  or the elements that contain the class `lister-item`.

Your second mistake is that you wait until you have finished iterating the sequence in order to `yield` the results.  By doing this you guarantee that this callback method will only produce one row in your csv file.

The solution to this would be to `yield` inside of the for loop so that it produces one row for each extracted title.

For example:

```
import scrapy

class ImdbHmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "imdb_hm"
    allowed_domains = ["www.imdb.com/"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.imdb.com/list/ls069761801/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('.lister-item'):
            title_name = title.xpath(".//h3/a/text()").get()
            yield {'title_name': title_name}
```